# How to issue an error if there is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, private

```
"use strict";

class Student {

  #
  name;#
  age;#
  city;#
  programmings;#
  os;


  constructor(name, age, city, programmings, os) {

    this.#name = name;
    this.#age = age;
    this.#city = city;
    this.#programmings = programmings;
    this.#os = os;

  }


  get getName() {

    let hiddenName = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#name.length; i++) {
      hiddenName += '*';
    }
    return 'Student name is ' + hiddenName;
  }


  get getAge() {

    let hiddenAge = '';
    let ageToString = this.#age.toString();

    for (let i = 0; i < ageToString.length; i++) {
      hiddenAge += '*';
    }
    return 'Student age is ' + hiddenAge;
  }

  get getCity() {

    let hiddenCity = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#city.length; i++) {
      hiddenCity += '*';
    }
    return 'Student city is ' + hiddenCity;
  }

  get getProgrammings() {

    let hiddenProgrammings = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#programmings.length; i++) {
      hiddenProgrammings += '*';
    }
    return 'Student programmings is ' + hiddenProgrammings;
  }

  get getOs() {

    let hiddenOs = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#os.length; i++) {
      hiddenOs += '*';
    }
    return 'Student os is ' + hiddenOs;
  }

}


const student = new Student('Ivan', 33, 'Moscow', 'Java', 'Windows');


console.log(student.name);
```

When accessing any field of an object, the result is directly output "undefined".
How to make it so that when accessing the object fields directly, an error is issued, the text of which I will write myself

for example: console.log(student.name);

output: 'Information is private'

Comment: JavaScript getters (and setters) work different than a language like Java. In Java you would have a method called `getVariable()` and access it as `obj.getVariable() <-- "blah blah"`, while in JS you would declare it simply without the prepended `get` naming convention in your method name, i.e. `get os()` or `get programmings()` and access it as `obj.os; <-- "os blah blah"` or `obj.programmings; <-- "programmings blah"`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
console.log(student.name ?? 'Information is private');
```

`??` is an IF statement but in shorter way.

It means if the value is set, the value is true and the value in the left side must be shown,  but if the value is not set, the value at the left side must be shown.

Comment: Great answer; can you explain to the OP what nullish coalescing is and what it does, though?

Comment: Can create some validate method and output 'Information is private'?

Comment: @code Ok let me edit my answer

Comment: @Noob No you dont need to create any method or function, just replace the `console.log` that I wrote with yours

Answer (score 0):

`student.name` calls `get name()` not `get getName()`

```js
"use strict";
class Student {
    #name;
    #age;
    #city;
    #programmings;
    #os;

    constructor(name, age, city, programmings, os) {
        this.#name = name;
        this.#age = age;
        this.#city = city;
        this.#programmings = programmings;
        this.#os = os;
    }

    get name() {
        return typeof this.#name === "undefined" ? "Information is private" : this.#name;
    }

    get getName() {
        let hiddenName = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < this.#name.length; i++) {
            hiddenName += "*";
        }
        return "Student name is " + hiddenName;
    }

    get getAge() {
        let hiddenAge = "";
        let ageToString = this.#age.toString();

        for (let i = 0; i < ageToString.length; i++) {
            hiddenAge += "*";
        }
        return "Student age is " + hiddenAge;
    }

    get getCity() {
        let hiddenCity = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < this.#city.length; i++) {
            hiddenCity += "*";
        }
        return "Student city is " + hiddenCity;
    }

    get getProgrammings() {
        let hiddenProgrammings = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < this.#programmings.length; i++) {
            hiddenProgrammings += "*";
        }
        return "Student programmings is " + hiddenProgrammings;
    }

    get getOs() {
        let hiddenOs = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < this.#os.length; i++) {
            hiddenOs += "*";
        }
        return "Student os is " + hiddenOs;
    }
}

const student = new Student("Ivan", 33, "Moscow", "Java", "Windows");

console.log(student.name);
```

Comment: It's a valid observation and gives the user expected output, but doesn't answer the question (to throw an error). Did you mean to comment?